# How to add items to dynamically created select (html) Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi
  How to add items to dynamically created select (html) Control..

thanks

Comment: do you want to add items at server side (or at client side)?

Comment: @VinayC , I need to add items at server side

Comment: use HtmlSelect.Items property - see my answer.

Answer (score 8):

For adding items on server side, use [HtmlSelect.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.items.aspx) property. For example,

```
var select = control as HtmlSelect; // may not be needed
var items = select.Items;
// Add items to the collection.
items.Add(new ListItem("apples", "1"));
items.Add(new ListItem("bananas", "2"));
items.Add(new ListItem("cherries", "3"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to do this e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddItem(Text,Value)
    {
        // Create an Option object        

        var opt = document.createElement("option");

        // Add an Option object to Drop Down/List Box
        document.getElementById("myDropDownList").options.add(opt);

        // Assign text and value to Option object
        opt.text = Text;
        opt.value = Value;

    }<script />
```