# Why 'innerhtml' does not work properly for 'select' tag

Tags: c#, html, browser

I am trying to set the `innerhtml` of an html `select` tag but I cannot set this feature;therefor,I need to use the `outerhtml` feature.This way,not only is my code `HARDCODE` ,but also it is preposterous.I have already read '[InnerHTML IE 8 doesn't work properly? Resetting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569915/innerhtml-ie-8-doesnt-work-properly-resetting-form)',it did not help though.

I would really appreciate it if you tell me how to set the `innerhtml` feature of an html `select` tag.
My C# code:

```
public void SetDefaultValue(string ControlID, string ControlValue) 
{      
    System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    HtmlElement HTMLControl = doc.GetElementById(ControlID);
        string ListResult;            
        string ListInnerHTML = "";
        ListInnerHTML += "<OPTION value = " + LstString + ">" + LstString + "</OPTION>";                                      
        ListResult = "<SELECT id = " + '"' + HTMLControl.Id + '"' + " type = " + '"' + HTMLControl.GetAttribute("type") + '"' + " title = " + '"' +
            HTMLControl.GetAttribute("title") + '"' + " name = " + '"' + HTMLControl.Name + '"' + " value = " + '"' + HTMLControl.GetAttribute("value") +
            '"' + " size = \"" + HTMLControl.GetAttribute("size") + '"' + HTMLControl.GetAttribute("multiple").ToString() + "\">" + ListInnerHTML + "</SELECT>";
        HTMLControl.OuterHtml = ListResult;                    
}
```

or

```
string _lsthtml = _htmlel.OuterHtml;
string[] _parts = ControlValue.Split(new char[] { ',' });
string _lstinner = "";
foreach (string _lst in _parts)
_lstinner += "<option value=" + _lst + ">" + _lst + "</option>";

_lsthtml = _lsthtml.Insert(_lsthtml.IndexOf(">") + 1, _lstinner);
_htmlel.OuterHtml = _lsthtml;
```

This code works but I need something efficient and clean.
The `ReturnControlType` function returns the `type` of an html tag.

Comment: why not use an asp:DropDownList?

Comment: @Pete:Because I need to do it in C#,it is not on the table.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem with using HtmlControl.InnerHtml?

Comment: could you post some code that shows in what special case innerHTML is not working?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    HtmlElement HTMLControl = doc.GetElementById(ControlID);
        string ListResult;            
        string ListInnerHTML = "";
        ListInnerHTML += "<OPTION value = " + LstString + ">" + LstString + "</OPTION>";
HTMLControl.InnerHtml = ListInnerHTML;

Comment: Repeating does not make the symptoms clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an official Internet Explorer bug:

[BUG: Internet Explorer Fails to Set the innerHTML Property of the Select Object](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228).

**One workaround**

You may try adding one of the following `meta` tags in your document's head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

You should also properly format the `option` tag's `value` attribute (enclose `LstString` in `'`):

```
ListInnerHTML += "<OPTION value='" + LstString + "'>" + LstString + "</OPTION>";
```

**A more reliable solution**

As the fixes above might be a workaround for your code, I would suggest to use a more reliable approach. Consider adding a reference to ***Microsoft.mshtml*** to your project and modifying your method like this:

```
// add this to the top of the file containing your class
using mshtml;

public void SetDefaultValue(string ControlID, string ControlValue)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    IHTMLDocument2 document = doc.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
    var sel = doc.GetElementById(ControlID);
    HTMLSelectElement domSelect = (HTMLSelectElement)sel.DomElement;
    domSelect.options.length = 0;
    HTMLOptionElement option;

    // here you can dynamically add the options to the select element
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        option = (HTMLOptionElement)document.createElement("option");
        option.text = String.Format("text{0}", i);
        option.value = String.Format("value{0}", i);
        domSelect.options.add(option, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know why innerHTML is not working for you.
If it just dosen't you could try an alternative:
http://innerdom.sourceforge.net/

[demo](http://innerdom.sourceforge.net/demo/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

In this thread it is sugested you use the items collection of a control
[How to add items to dynamically created select (html) Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631024/how-to-add-items-to-dynamically-created-select-html-control)

refer to this page for a complete example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.items.aspx

Comment: Adding options in code-behind using the Items collection is more logical, more high-level, and easier, than using innerHtml.